# How safe is system("/bin/ls");

Tags: c, linux, security

I understand that if you override PATH variable, you can make calls such as `system("ls");` do whatever you want.

But how can one bypass a call to  `system("/bin/ls");` when the user does not have write permission to `/bin /ls` ?

Please, don't tell me that this is not OS compatible, I know and this is not the point of the question.

Thanks !

Comment: [man chroot](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chroot)

Comment: @CarlNorum AFAIK only superuser (to be correct anyone having CAP_SYS_CHROOT capability) can perform a chroot...what more could he gain by fooling the program with a fake `/bin/ls`?

Comment: Probably asking it on http://security.stackexchange.com will match much better the site profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will cause something like:

```
execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "/bin/ls"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
```

so does not give much room to manoeuvre, and while one can create a `function /bin/ls { ... }`, it appears for the above call that when `sh` is actually `bash` the `bash` rc files are not read, and the function is not called.

```
$ /bin/ls
hello world
$ type -a /bin/ls
/bin/ls is a function
/bin/ls () 
{ 
    echo hello world
}
/bin/ls is /bin/ls
$ cat dols.c
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    system("/bin/ls");
    return 0;
}
$ ./dols
dols  dols.c  trace.9594  trace.9595
$
```

Apart from environment hacks (e.g. making `ls` link with some other library via `LD_` variables) or a shell shock class vulnerability (e.g. a bug in `sh` itself), this is probably okay. (It would not be okay if someone who doesn't know about these concerns then edited to code to be an unsafe shell command...)

Answer (score 0):

A user can define `ls` and `/bin/ls` as functions.

With...

```
ls () { echo 'No.'; }
```

And...

```
/bin/ls () { echo 'NO!'; }
```

However, you can protect against this a little by unsetting `ls` and `/bin/ls` before executing them...

With...

```
unset -f ls /bin/ls
```

Comment: These are *shell functions* and are only visible to a shell. This sort of thing would be totally invisible to an `exec` call.

Comment: The `system()` routine actually invokes the shell (normally `/bin/sh`) so these concerns are not 100% far-fetched.  Luckily, there doesn't seem to be any way to leak or sneak those into the shell started by `system()`.